Did Proto-Indo-European use prepositions, postpositions, or both?
I’m trying to mix this protolanguage with another one by overlapping them, and none of the search results are being helpful. I doubt the many articles would either. I’d also like to know if the adpositions were derived from nouns, verbs, or both.

Proto-Indo-European had no prepositions. It used adverbs instead.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Indo-European_particles

An interesting question, probably unanswerable as every verb has a verbal noun. Consider a different question - what are English prepositions derived from - the answer seems to be: OE prepositions (of); adverbs (before); nouns (in front of).  We can tell this because we know historic versions of English. We don't know the foregoers of Indo-European so in many cases any answer is guesswork. The only thing we can be certain of is that some are developed from nouns ('ḫ2enti') but only because the nouns still exist or at least are recorded (English 'end'; Hittite 'ḫants'='forehead').

Look at Schleicher's fable to see how a language without adpositions can work.

PIE did not actually use prepositions, but rather it used adverbs or even noun roots (for nouns like "front", "back", "side", "middle", "end") in locative case to describe relative locations of objects and actions (think about something like "centri", "fronti", "endi", "sidi").
Still, this is a good summary of PIE "prepositions".
